# css to word break the p tag containing a tag

Tags: html, css

I have html as below

```
<p>Read the <a target="_blank" class="highlight" href="www.url.com">'Design Network Hierarchy and Settings'</a> chapter in your version's user guide to learn how to create the structure and framework of your network including the physical topology, network settings, and device type profiles that you can apply to devices throughout your network.</p>
```

the a tag part of paragraph breaks into separate line and seen as below:

[image]

but I want it to be seen it as uniform paragraph.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: the text inside the quotes (which is part of anchor tag) is moving to next line, i want it to be in same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any CSS it seems to work. Check your `highlight` class, it might define something that causes your link to be in a separate line. Probably 
`display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

Try adding `display: inline`, it should work

```css
p{
 width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Read the
  <a target="_blank" class="highlight" href="www.url.com">'Design Network Hierarchy and Settings'</a> chapter in your version's user guide to learn how to create the structure and framework of your network including the physical topology, network settings,
  and device type profiles that you can apply to devices throughout your network.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set display: inline-block for a tag

Answer (score 0):

fix was simple, adding `display:inline` to a tag has solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` to force the text to remain on the same line.
Read more about white-space [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Working example found [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOBqew)

Answer (score 0):

By default `<a>` tags are inline elements. Make sure you are not modifying the display property of `<a>`. You can inspect it in browser and find it easily. If you note something changing the display property, either remove it or overwrite it by applying `display: inline`